# while and eof won't work

Tags: c, scanf, eof

my while cyclus wont work when i want to close it with CTRL+C

```
while(1){
    res=scanf("%d",&k); 
    if(res != 1){
        printf("Bad input.\n")
        return 1;
    }
    else if((k <= 0)){
        printf("Bad input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(res == EOF){
        return 0;
    }
    a=one(arr, arr_size, k);
    b=two(arr, arr_size, k);
    c=three(arr, arr_size, k);
    printf("Sum: %d\n",a+b+c);  
}
```

It just shows me Bad input when I want to close it CTRL+D. I want only to close program with `return 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first test you do is on `res`, and `EOF` is in fact just the number `-1`, which is not equal to `1`, causing the first `if` to resolve to true and returning with `1`.

This should work:

```
while(1) {
    res=scanf("%d",&k); 

    /* first check for EOF */
    if(res == EOF){
        return 0;
    }
    /* then check input */
    if(res != 1 || k <= 0) {
        printf("Bad input.\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for help but another problem is when i scanf 3.8 or some double number it will call my functions one two three and then it will printf Bad input because of double number ... i want to close when its not interger number before calling function